# Opening dialog box in 2010 CSS font changes

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, modal-dialog

I've had this issue all along with my 2010 Foundation intranet site I maintain, and am wondering what I can do to resolve it. Here is the situation it arises in:

I open a dialog box within sharepoint, and notice the fonts in the underlying page change, then flicker back to the set CSS font-family. It is very noticable because the whole page's fonts change then change back to normal just as fast.

It's a minor annoyance, yes, but I hear from lots of people about it. Is there anything that can be done to prevent the font from changing/reverting?

Answer (score 0):

When I started using font-awesome icons it become annoying and very un-user friendly to see the font disappear when a user opened a modal dialog box, to edit a task for instance. What is actually happening in my case is being a strictly IE8 company we experience ie8 bugs, of which there are many (especially CSS wise). For the fonts in question I've created an IE8 only css file loaded on a conditional statement in my master page, and from there I've made sure the font-family for each css selector contains only one font. This seems to have fixed all my font problems I experience so far.